# JSON to custom PHP object instance

Tags: php, json, object, casting

Lets say we have a PHP class invoice and items :

```
class Item{
    public $CID;
    public $CATID;             // category id...
    public $net;
    public $t1;
    public $t2;
    public $total;
}

class invoice{
    public $items = array();        //array of object item;
    public $date;
    public $title;
    public $description;
    public $subtotal;
    public $t1;
    public $t2;
    public $total;


    public function __construct(){
    }
}
```

The object invoice contains several methods like: add item, remove_item, recalculate, set taxes and stuff... it's kinda complex. 
I figured out how to parse an instance of this object to javascript using:

```
$json=json_encode((array)$invoice);
```

Then in javascript, I have the exact same object definition, same methods and then I use :

```
test = jQuery.parseJSON('<?php= $json?>');
test.__proto__ = invoice.prototype;
```

So far so good, my test variable has now became an invoice object in javascript, and I can use methods defined in invoice and item javascript classes. After a few manipulations I can resend the object to php (lets say by ajax), using the following:

```
function send_ajax(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: ({
             invoice:JSON.stringify(test)
        }),
        success: function(msg){
            $('#response').html(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Then, serverside I use json_decode to transform the json into an array. This is where I'm stuck! I cannot cast my $invoice[] or stdObjcect into my invoice class. I also code in ASP .net C# and such thing is really easily achieved. The reason why I would need to achieve such thing is simple: I need to use methods from my php invoice class to the parsed JSON...  Anybody has Ideas?

the only thing I came up with before is to parse manually the json object... Are there any other "built-in" ways

```
  public function __construct($json = null){
        if ($json != null){
           $json=json_decode($json, true);

           for($i=0;$i<count($json[items]);$i++){
               $newItem= new Item();
                foreach ($json[items][$i] as $key=>$value){
                    $newItem->$key=$value;
                }
               array_push($this->items,$newItem);
           }
            foreach($json as $key =>$value){
                if(!is_array($value)){
                $this->$key=$value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you do this?? PHP != JS.

Comment: @PeeHaa I believe the answer lies in `I also code in ASP.net C#`...

Comment: Well Prototypal Inheritance is different from the classical object inheritence model.

Comment: I know PHP != JS, and this operation contains certain risks, but this is a backend application project, where only the admin would have access (they wont try to hack their own system). In such a case working with symetrical objects serverside and client side makes everything so much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what ASP does but trying to create some kind of serializing between different languages is not the best solution.

You should define a protocol that JavaScript and PHP talk with between each other. Where the JS and PHP sides loads the specific values into their own object structures.

The PHP class might have a method that knows about a specific array structure and which fields to put in which instance variables.

```
public function loadJSON(array $data) {
    $this->title = $data['Title'];
    ...
}
```